# How to do PDF snipping (image extraction) with filename added to image?

Tags: pdf, filenames, tags, pdf-reader, snipping

I was doing some literature research and was copying together (extract figure in Adobe PDF) figures from a large number of papers. It is super tedious to keep track from which publication, which figure came from.

Do you know about an app/pdf reader, that automatically adds e.g. the filename (like a watermark) to a snipped/extracted image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a rudimentary python script that does the job. In case anyone comes by.
Regards

https://github.com/bebissig/pdf_watermarker